# How to make ATLAS to be Avaliable for Octave?

Tags: multithreading, octave, multicore, atlas

I have been using octave for some Machine Learning algorithms, but when using Neural Networks, it uses the 100% of 1 core, I would like it to use all my 4 cores, I read this could be done with atlas, but when I tryed to install it on ubuntu (13), I noticed it was already installed; Nevertheless, it looks that octave can't see it

Best Regards!

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889118/get-gnu-octave-to-work-with-a-multicore-processor-multithreading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way of increasing the usage of CPU cores is vectorizing your Neural Network implementation.

More information about vectorization can be found in the following tutorial.

http://ufldl.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Vectorization

Comment: I already Implemented Vectorization, And Optimized my Octave code, but It's not quite resource-efficient.

Best Regards!