# Is there any way that I can use thread in octave as like in java

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, octave

as follow the title, I'm looking for the way so I can use thread or something that can speed up my calculation in octave.

Who has any idea, or function, or package??? please help me.
and FYI i'm using windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Octave supports multi-threading on Linux through libraries that are multi-threaded. See [Get GNU Octave to work with a multicore processor. (Multithreading)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889118/get-gnu-octave-to-work-with-a-multicore-processor-multithreading) Atlas supports Windows through Cyqwin http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/faq.html#where I've used the libraries on Gentoo Linux and had some speed improvements when running single processes. The libraries automatically divide some operations between multiple processors. This isn't the optimal solution of course as it only works well when dealing with very large matrices. It also might be difficult to get running on Windows. I know I had some issues with Linux. When tuning the libraries, do not use multiple jobs for compiling (see your compiler docs). It failed every time I tried that.

A better solution is if you can divide your problem into smaller problems that are independent of each other so that their order of execution doesn't matter. I wrote a small Perl script to break up multiple calls to Octave with pieces of the problem as Octave doesn't have a native way of creating threads. Since you're on Windows, it will need some adjustments unless you use it from Cyqwin.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -wT

$ENV{PATH} = "/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin";
use strict;
use POSIX qw(setsid :sys_wait_h);
use Time::Piece;
use Time::Local;

#------------------- GLOBALS -----------------------

my $go_me = 0;
my $kid = 0;
my $kid_pid = 0;
my $num_children = 0;

#------------- SUBROUTINES ----------------------

sub Interrupt
{  $go_me = 0;  }

sub Interrupt_Die
{
   $go_me = 0;
   print localtime . " > $$ - Dieing: @_ $!\n";
   exit(0);
}

sub Child_Is_Done
{  $num_children++;  }

#------------------ PROCESS OVERHEAD -------------------------

if($#ARGV != 1)
{
   print "Usage: octbatch /path/filename [concurrency number]\n";
   exit(0);
}

my $stdout_file = "";

if($ENV{HOME} =~ m/^(\/home\/\w+)$/)
{
  $stdout_file = "$1" . '/octbatch.log';
}
else
{
  print "Invalid value for $ENV{HOME}\nDon't run as root.\n";
  exit(0);
}

open STDIN,'/dev/null' or die "Can't read /dev/null: $!";
open STDOUT,'>',$stdout_file  or die "Can't write to $stdout_file: $!";
open(STDERR, ">&STDOUT")  or die "Can't write to $stdout_file: $!";
defined(my $pid = fork) or die "Can't fork: $!";
exit if $pid;
setsid or die "Can't start a new session: $!";
my $parent = "$$";
print "Parent process is: $parent\n";
$go_me = 1;
print localtime . " > $$ - Starting.\n";

#----------------------- MAIN CYCLE ---------------------------------

my $filename = $ARGV[0];
unless(open(COMMANDFILE, "<$filename"))
{  die "Could not open $filename $!\n";  }
$num_children = $ARGV[1];
$SIG{'CHLD'} = 'Child_Is_Done';

while($go_me and my $line = <COMMANDFILE>)
{
   if($num_children <= 0 and $kid_pid)
   {
      my $child_pid = -1;
      $child_pid = wait();
      if(WIFEXITED($?))
      {  print localtime . " > $$ - Process $child_pid exited\n";  }
   }

   chomp($line);
   print localtime . " > $$ - Running $line\n";
   $num_children--;
   Interrupt_Die("Can't fork!") unless defined($kid_pid = fork());

   if($kid_pid)
   {
      print localtime . " > $$ - I am the parent.\n";
      $SIG{'CHLD'} = 'Child_Is_Done';
   }
   else
   {
      print localtime . " > $$ - I am the child.\n";
      $go_me = 0;
      $kid = 1;
      print localtime . " > $$ - Running $line\n";

      if($line =~ m/^(octave ([^;\n\r]+))$/)
      {
         $line = "$1";
         system("$line");
      }
      else
      {
         print localtime . " > $$ - Invalid line. Skipping.\n";
      }
   }
}

if($kid)
{
   print localtime . " > $$ - Process $$ exited\n";
   exit(0);
}
else
{
   my $child_pid = -1;

   do
   {
      $child_pid = waitpid(-1,0);
      if(WIFEXITED($?))
      {  print localtime . " > $$ - Process $child_pid exited\n";  }
   } while($child_pid > 0);

   print localtime . " > $$ - Stopping: $!\n";
   exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On [Octave-Forge](http://octave.sourceforge.net) are two packages dealing with parallel computing:

- [mpi](http://octave.sourceforge.net/mpi/)
- [parallel](http://octave.sourceforge.net/parallel/index.html)

It is also possible to spawn subprocesses using the `fork()` function.