# Do any of Octaves minimization functions utilize multi-core/threaded processing?

Tags: octave, multicore

I'm composing a pretty heavy duty octave function that needs to be minimized with a function such as `fminunc` (technically I *can* constrain the variables, but I need to minimize over multiple variables).

A cursory reading of google and Octave documentation suggests that this is a single-threaded process. Are there any options to utilize multi-core/threaded processing here?

I'm on a 12 core box, it feels sad to leave 91% of the compute capacity unused.

Matlab appears to have something useful in this respect with `fmincon`:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/examples/minimizing-an-expensive-optimization-problem-using-parallel-computing-toolbox.html

Comment: As far as I can tell, no. If you really care about optimization performance, choose another language.

Comment: Yeah, seems like it to me too. I guess choose matlab in this case. Thanks for the response!

Comment: I was not talking about MATLAB, but anyways, good luck.

Comment: I realize... MATLAB was my comment as it does possess a multithreaded minimization function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like the answer I actually needed. The minimizer may not run multithreaded, but the matrix operations in the function I'm minimizing can.

[Get GNU Octave to work with a multicore processor. (Multithreading)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889118/get-gnu-octave-to-work-with-a-multicore-processor-multithreading)